# Resizing a UITextView programmatically in Swift 2 to enlarge its width

Tags: uitableview, swift2

EDIT: I post a screenshot of what I would like to implement in iPad and iPhone. When using the button in iPhone, the UITableView opens and has to cover a part of the UITextView.

[image]

I have a universal project for iPhone and iPad. In the main storyboard there are two controls, an UITextField and a UITableView. The UITextField keeps the left 1/3 portion of the screen and the UITableView the remaining part of the screen.

When in iPhone, I hide the UITableView and I would like that the UITextView keeps all the screen. Then, when the user taps on a button, the UITableView appears over the text field (I dismiss the UITableView as soon as the user selects a choice).

How can I have the tableView to enlarge in a way that its right border, go to the right border of the screen?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement what you described is to start with the TableView "outside" of the scene, with a negative Leading Space to the main view. Them when users press the button, the value of the Leading Space Constraint is set to zero.

Example:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

ViewController code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewLeadingMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func revealTableView(sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            3.0,
            animations: {
                self.tableViewLeadingMargin.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

There's just one caveat: you'll need to adjust the width of the TableView programatically, based on the iPhone screen size.

The answer above the iPhone issue. For iPad, I'd suggest using **Size Classes**, creating a specific layout/constraints for them:

[image: sizeClasses]

To illustrate:

[image: sizeClasseForIpad]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need one clarification. When the app runs on an iPad the TextView occupies 2 thirds of the space, when the app runs on an iPhone the same TextView has to occupy all the width space. How can I resize the TextField programmatically in viewDidLoad()? Are you so kind to help me to transform this pseudo code in a real Swift 2 code? (please see below)

Comment: let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
        
        if model == "iPhone" {
            mainTextFieldRightBorder = rightBorderOfMainView // pseudo code (don't actually work)
        }

Comment: Hi. For iPad, I suggest using Size Classes. This way you'll have a specific layout/constraints for them and would not need to adjust it programatically. I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I included an example on how to use Size Classes to create iPad layouts.

Comment: I  ferunandu, thank you for your useful suggestion, being a beginner with few experience, I will need a bit of time to transform your suggestions in code, so be patient whether I will ask some more info please. I'm sorry but I had not seen that you had asked me a screenshot of the scene, I added it in the question. It is how I would like to implement the project for the iPhone and iPad.

Comment: That's ok. Based on the screenshot you added, I think the approach I suggested will do the trick. You just need to learn how to use Size Classes. Then you'll be using the iPhone solution and iPad solution I posted, each one on its own adaptive layout. Please refer to this (focus on Size Classes): https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started